# Python - evaulate elements in list of lists

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, nested-lists

Trying to learn Python and got this task to find if there is a consecutive year-over-year improvement (higher score) from 2003-2018 for any of the countries.

Given list:

```
lst=[[;2018;2015;2012;2009;2006;2003],[Country1;558;544;538;525;525;527],[Country2;551;548;561;555;547;550],[Country3;545;538;536;534;533;529],[Country4;526;524;554;546;547;542]]
```

The list is a lot longer than the sample. The countries with counsecutive year-over-year improvement shall be presented in a table. Second task is to do the same, but for countries with year-over-year lower score.

No imports are allowed.

I'm think that I need to do some if-searches in a for-loop, but I'm drawing a blank here really. I can't wrap me head around it really.

Any strategy tip or code samples are much appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is your criteria? Does it have to be at least one YoY improvement? last year better than the first one? Always has to improve with each year?

Comment: The criteria is that it must improve each year.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this.

```
lst = [
    ['',2018,2015,2012,2009,2006,2003],
    ["Country1",558,544,538,525,525,524],
    ["Country2",551,548,561,555,547,550],
    ["Country3",545,538,536,534,533,529],
    ["Country4",526,524,554,546,547,542]
]

_, *year_data = lst.pop(0)
countries = lst


def is_decreasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data < last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True


def is_increasing(lst) -> bool:
    last_checked, *rest = lst
    for year_data in rest:
        if year_data > last_checked:
            last_checked = year_data
        else:
            return False
    return True


def find_yoy():
    increasing_yoy = []
    decreasing_yoy = []

    for country in countries:
        country_name, *country_data = country
        assert len(year_data) == len(country_data)
        sorted_year_data, sorted_country_data = zip(*sorted(zip(year_data, country_data)))

        if is_increasing(sorted_country_data):
            increasing_yoy.append(country_name)
        elif is_decreasing(sorted_country_data):
            decreasing_yoy.append(country_name)

    print("countries with increasing yoy:", ', '.join(increasing_yoy), '.')
    print("countries with decreasing yoy:", ','.join(decreasing_yoy), '.')

find_yoy()
```

If performance matters, merge `is_decreasing` and `is_increasing` into one function.

Comment: Cheers, but I'm not allowed to use any imports.

Comment: lol its just static typing for your IDE, remove it if you want

Comment: Tested, works! But... Country1 has not a consecutive increase, between 2006-2009 it goes from 525 to 525, so it should be false. Changed from >= to only >, but this gives me no YoY increase for Country3, which it should. Strange. Why?

Comment: Oh, there was a small bug. I was iterating over `lst` instead of `rest`. Please accept this answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: It did! I accepted your answer but got this: "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I have to low reputation :( Thanks for the help anyway!

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You triggered me so hard. If you think a question doesn't meet SO guidelines, just raise a flag and people will vote. I'm happy if I was able to help someone, especially if it's a newbie. Also, downvoting because of the reasons you listed is kind of against guidelines. [when to downvote questions from docs](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) and  [answers from meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/why-do-you-cast-downvotes-on-answers)

Comment: Note that your most upvoted answer (which also happens to be really good) is literally for `gimme teh code` question. It's even worse than this question, from the new contributor.

Comment: It felt like it was reinforcing OP's misunderstanding of our rules by saying "here's your code" to OP's "gimme the code". If you'd like, I'll remove my downvote if you edit your answer to include some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I'd use the differences between each years, like so

```
lst=[[2018,2015,2012,2009,2006,2003],["Country1",558,544,538,525,525,527],["Country2",551,548,561,555,547,550],["Country3",545,538,536,534,533,529],["Country4",526,524,554,546,547,542]]

for list in lst[1:]:
    nums = list[1:]
    print([nextnum - num for num, nextnum in zip(nums, nums[1:])])
```

Then you can make a simple loop checking where the differences stay positive/negative

Comment: Tried your solution, but got a confusing answer. 
[-14, -6, -13, 0, 2]
[-3, 13, -6, -8, 3]
[-7, -2, -2, -1, -4]
[-2, 30, -8, 1, -5]

The first list (years) starts with single quotation marks, ['', '2018', '2015', '2012', '2009', '2006', '2003'].

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you want to represent this as a table, but to calculate YoY you can do it like this:

```
def yoy(y1, y2):
    return (y2 - y1) / y1
```

And then apply it on your list to find out which countries have improved year by year:

```
for row in lst[1:]:
    # calculate YoY
    country_yoys = []
    for y1, y2 in zip(row[1:], row[2:]):
        gain = yoy(y1, y2)
        country_yoys.append(gain)
    
    # Check if each YoY has an improvement
    counsecutive_yoy_improv = all(sum(country_yoys[i:i+2]) > 0 for i in range(1, len(country_yoys)+1))
    
    # Print results
    if counsecutive_yoy_improv:
        print(f"Country \"{row[0]}\" has been doing good!")
    else:
        print(f"Country \"{row[0]}\" has been doing bad!")
```